# Saving web session from an open login form in Python

Tags: python, python-requests, scrape

I'm writing a Python script for a small app that needs to web-scrape. The content I want is behind a login screen, but because of the nature of the webpage (and my use case) I'd prefer to present the actual login screen to the user rather than posting saved variables from the Python script.

Is there a way I can present the user the official login page to the site in a window and capture the session to use in my program (with Requests, Eel, Electron or similar)?

```
POSTLOGINURL = 'www.example.com/login'
REQUESTURL = 'www.example.com/page_to_scrape'

    payload = {'username': 'myusername', 'password': 'mypassword'}

    with requests.Session() as session:
        post = session.post(POSTLOGINURL, data=payload)
        t = print(session)
        r = session.get(REQUESTURL)
        print(r.text)
```

The REQUESTURL page (seemingly logged in) prints as an 'identifying my digital identity' page that would usually redirect with JavaScript in the browser to the requested page. Is there a way around it with the tools above or similar (the verification only happens once)?

Answer (score 1):

The login session is probably stored in a cookie.
So you can save the cookie information.

```py
with requests.Session() as session:
        post = session.post(POSTLOGINURL, data=payload)
        t = print(session)
        r = session.get(REQUESTURL)
        cookie = session.cookie
        with open('somefile', 'wb') as f:
            pickle.dump(cookie, f)
```

Then just load the file in to the session the next time.

```py
session = requests.session()
with open('somefile', 'rb') as f:
    session.cookies.update(pickle.load(f))
```